# Load another page's HTML and parse it through selectors with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried as example on jsFiddle

```
$.get('/user/login/', function(content){  /* (jsFiddle.net/user/login is in the same domain) */
    alert($('*',content).html()); 
});
```

But it returns

```
<a href="/">JSFiddle</a>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd like to fetch HTML's title for instance, but $('title',content) is not working

Comment: think how will jsfiddle understand this `/user/login/` url .

Comment: no, I called their login page, in the same domain

Comment: If you try locally, make sure you run it through a webserver. AJAX calls won't work if you use the file:// protocol.

Comment: Well it was the fastest link avilable. I am just going to get a site's intra-domain public page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle as far as I know won't allow AJAX calls.

**EDIT: But they do offer some sort of simulation although I've not used it http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html**

Answer (score 1):

Can do this without Ajax.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load remote content into object element</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="siteloader"></div>​
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://tired.com/">');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After getting the page try to parse it.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to load content, only parse some values, like title

Answer (score 1):

it will check jsfiddles login page. something like

```
http://jsfiddle.net/user/login/
```

you can use something like `/echo/json/` as url:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<p>JSON will be received in 3 seconds</p>
<ul id='post'></ul>
</div>

new Request.JSON({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        json: JSON.encode({
            text: 'some text',
            array: [1, 2, 'three'],
            object: {
                par1: 'another text',
                par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
                par3: {}
            }
        }),
        delay: 3
    },
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        show_response(response, $('post'));
    }
}).send();

show_response = function(obj, result) {
    $H(obj).each(function(v, k) {
        new Element('li', {
            text: k + ': ' + v
        }).inject(result);
    });
    result.highlight();
};
```

jsfiddle demo:http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/QsHw4/#